# import org.hibernate not working in JDeveloper

Tags: hibernate, jdeveloper

I am using JDeveloper 10g. When I try to import org.hibernate it is showing doesnot exist error. I have imported the hibernate libraries by using Tools-->Manage Libraries and then add the path to to the jar files. I have added the below jars:

hibernate3.jar,
hibernate-validator-3.0.0.ga60992.jar,

But the error is still coming, Am I missing something somewhere or there is other way to import the jars in JDeveloper or do I need to change the config file?

Thanks. Biswa

Answer (score 0):

When posting questions on JDeveloper always state the exact version of JDeveloper, the IDE has gone through significant improvements on each release.  As example for 10g, there was a big difference between then 10.1.2 and 10.1.3 versions of the product, the later introducing support for JSF as a primary citizen in the IDE.

I also wonder why you're using such an old version of JDeveloper? But I'll assume you have a valid reason like supporting an old application.

In addressing your specific question, via the Tools -> Manage Libraries option you're simply managing what JARs are attached to each library, this doesn't directly relate to what JARs are accessible from your code.  The library is a template like function for creating a named set of JARs, essentially a named library, which you then associate with each application workspace project to make use of.  This saves you the trouble of attaching every single JAR to your workspace projects again and again.

So what's not clear from your post, is the library associated with the workspace project you're interested in using the JAR from?  You can determine this by right clicking on the project you're interested in accessing the JAR from, selecting Project Properties -> Libraries and Classpaths, then attaching the relevant library with Add Library button.  Alternatively via the same set of options, you could add the Hibernate JAR directly without using the library facility.

Answer (score 0):

You added the libs to the tool not to your project.
Go into project properties and under the libraries section add either the JARs directly or the libraries you created.